# Mongo DB 4.4 AddEncoding Hook Is decommissioned , what to use now?

Tags: mongodb, bson

I am trying to upgrade the mongo driver 4.4 from 3.12 and notice that BSON file is entirely removed.

There is a method in this class addEncodingHooks in 3.12 where we can add a transformer .
But in 4.4 BSON class is itself removed.

Does anyone knows how to achieve similar functionality in mongo db 4.4 ?

Manish

Comment: Have you looked in the new BSON class? https://mongodb.github.io/mongo-java-driver/4.4/apidocs/bson/

Comment: Yes Looked but could not found anything